# Como definir um XOR no JS, no caso dessa questão é necessário que retorne como se fosse uma tabela verdade do "XOR"

Tags: javascript

```
function xor(true,false){
  return (true && false) && (false &&true) !(true && true) && (false && false);
}
```

Comment: Aline, o XOR retorna `true` apenas se as entradas são diferentes... Então `a != b` é equivalente a `a xor b` para valores booleanos...

Comment: Consegui resolver, obrigada Fernando!
solução: 
 function xor(a,b){
  return a != b;
}